# #include <file.h> file not found issue in C++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, qt-creator, godot

So I am trying to compile and modify the godot and godot-cpp libraries from source, where the godot-cpp has dependencies on godot. However, In all the files for godot-cpp, I am receiving:

```
#include <godot/gdnative_interface.h>  ||  godot.hpp:33:10: error: 'godot/gdnative_interface.h' file not found
```

I assume this is because the compiler is looking in my include path in the system folders rather than in my Documents folder udner home, which is where I built godot from source. How do I redirect godot-cpp to look for godot in my Documents folder? godot uses scons to build, and I am using Qtcreator and Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: add wherever it is located to your include paths?

Comment: Attempted this first, didn't work for me. I included the folder that has gdnative_interface.h to my path variables and still the same result.

Comment: you need to add the parent directory for the path you are including,

Answer (score 0):

Just put " instead of < and >

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).